# Why is my destructor never called?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a base class A and a derived class B:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual f();
};

class B : public A
{
public:
     B()
     {
         p = new char [100];
     }
     ~B()
     {
         delete [] p;
     }
     f();
private:
    char *p;
};
```

For any reason the destructor is never called - why? I dont understand this.

Comment: Although everyone already figured out what the problem is(As it is a FAQ in C++), I still suggest you should show the code how you use the class B.(If you use it this way: B* p = new B(); delete p; and the destructor never called, then it should be totally different problem.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your base class needs a virtual destructor. Otherwise the destructor of the derived class will not be called, if only a pointer of type A* is used.

Add

```
virtual ~A() {};
```

to class A.

Comment: is there any reason for not using this virtual destructor in main class?

Answer (score 7):

Class A should have a virtual destructor. Without that, derive class destructors won't be called.

Comment: Won't be called iff the destructor is called via a pointer to A.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual f();
};

class B : public A
{
public:
     B()
     {
         p = new char [100];
     }
     virtual ~B() // virtual keywork optional but occasionally helpful for self documentation.
     {
         delete [] p;
     }
     f();
private:
    char *p;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If your variable is of type A it doesn't have a virtual destructor and so it won't look at the actual runtime type of the object to determine it needs to call the desstructor

Add an empty destructor to A

virtual ~A() {}

and that should fix it.

In general you need to do this on any class that can possibly be used as a base class.