# clang & gcc don't warn about non-virtual base destructors for polymorphism when using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, virtual-destructor

We know that <strike>if there are virtual functions then the base class destructor should be marked as virtual as well, otherwise it is undefined behavior when explicitly `deleted` with base class pointer</strike> if we hope to delete derived object with base class pointer the base destructor should be marked as virtual, otherwise it is undefined behavior.

For example,

```
struct Base {
  virtual void greet() { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  virtual void greet() override { std::cout << "derived\n"; }
};
```

call

```
Base *b = new Derived;
b->greet();
delete (b);
```

clang(gcc similarly) will emit such a warning when **-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor**:

```
delete called on 'Base' that has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
```

But **neither** of them report warnings for *smart pointers*:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> sb = std::make_unique<Derived>();
//   std::unique_ptr<Base> sb = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived);
sb->greet();
```

I guess this still leads to undefined behavior, right?

Comment: Well, your first sentence lumps up several unrelated things. The rule is that deleting derived class through base class pointer is UB if the destructor is non-virtual. That's all there is to it. Whether the class has any other virtual functions is completely irrelevant. Presence of other virtual functions is just a loose rule-of-the-thumb criterion that suggests that this class is *relatively likely* to be deleted through a base class pointer.

Comment: @AndreyT thanks for pointing out that, i updated the original question to avoid misunderstanding. But I just discover that gcc/clang won't emit warnings if no `virtual functions` called, why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's still undefined behavior. The problem is that the `delete` call happens inside `std::default_delete`, which is inside a system header. By default, the compiler doesn't generate warnings for code in system headers.

If you pass [`-Wsystem-headers`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dbbfc03e9df9916), you'll see the warning. Unfortunately, it's buried inside a pile of other warnings.

Comment: too many diagnostics that i guess regular programmers will never use `-Wsystem-headers`; in this sense we have to be more careful ourselves:-(

Comment: @HongxuChen Yeah, I am *really* disappointed to discover this; it astounds me that `unique_ptr` is in any way *less* safe to use than raw pointers. Fortunately, both GCC and Clang do have `-Wnon-virtual-dtor`, which warns about non-virtual destructors even if you don't try to `delete` a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Not mentioned yet by the other answers:

This problem only exists for `unique_ptr`, not for the `shared_ptr`.

Both of these smart pointers can have custom deleters; however `unique_ptr` defaults to deleting the base pointer, and `shared_ptr` defaults to deleting the derived pointer (if you used `make_shared<Derived>` or equivalent).

Another way to solve the problem is to supply your own custom deleter for `unique_ptr` that deletes the derived pointer. This might be a good solution for cases where you want to avoid the overhead of introducing a vtable.

Further reading: [`unique_ptr` deleter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060497/deleting-derived-classes-in-stdunique-ptrbase-containers?noredirect=1),  [`shared_ptr` deleter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899790/shared-ptr-magic)

Answer (score 0):

As of clang [r312167](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=312167) (which will be in clang 6.0 when it's released in about half a year), clang's `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` warning will warn about this.